# All possible combinations of 5 variables, each of which has 2 sub-variables.

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm looking for an equation to determine the number of possible combinations of five separate variables, each of which can be two sub-variables. However, the sub-variables for one master variable are not necessarily the same as for the other master variables.

For example, I have letters A-E. A can be 0.7 or 1.6, B can be 15, or 0, C can be 40 or 0, etc.

I have found several situations that seem close, but the results don't seem to be making sense, and I am struggling to bridge the gap.

Comment: numerical values are not variables ...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are choosing one of the five variables, then choosing one of the two values that variable can assume?  How many such choices are there?  You can use a tree diagram.  This is a [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) problem.